# Mapping of different types with generics

Tags: go, generics

How to map 2 different types (Car, Bicycle) with one generic mapping function (Map2Vehicle) to a Vehicle type. Car and Bicycle cannot be changed, because it's auto generated code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := Car{Name: "MyCar", Wheels: CarWheels{Count: 4}}
    b := Bicycle{Name: "MyBicycle", Wheels: BicycleWheels{Count: 2}}
    v1 := Map2Vehicle(&c)
    v2 := Map2Vehicle(&b)
    fmt.Println(v1.Name, v2.Name)
}

// ---------------- Car
type Car struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels CarWheels
}

type CarWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (c *Car) GetName() string      { return c.Name }
func (c *Car) GetWheels() CarWheels { return c.Wheels }
func (w *CarWheels) GetCount() int  { return w.Count }

// ---------------- Bicycle

type Bicycle struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels BicycleWheels
}

type BicycleWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (b *Bicycle) GetName() string          { return b.Name }
func (b *Bicycle) GetWheels() BicycleWheels { return b.Wheels }
func (w *BicycleWheels) GetCount() int      { return w.Count }

// ---------------- Vehicle

type wheels interface {
    GetCount() int
}

type vehicle[T wheels] interface {
    GetName() string
    GetWheels() T
}

type Vehicle struct {
    Name string
}

func Map2Vehicle[T vehicle[wheels]](v T) *Vehicle {
    return &Vehicle{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s with %d wheels", v.GetName(), v.GetWheels().GetCount()),
    }
}
```

**Error**: The code does not work:

```
cmd/tmp/tmp.go:8:19: *Car does not satisfy vehicle[wheels] (wrong type for method GetWheels)
                have GetWheels() CarWheels
                want GetWheels() wheels
cmd/tmp/tmp.go:9:19: *Bicycle does not satisfy vehicle[wheels] (wrong type for method GetWheels)
                have GetWheels() BicycleWheels
                want GetWheels() wheels
```

**Expected output:**

```
MyCar with 4 wheels MyBicycle with 2 wheels
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem with golang generics?

Answer (score 2):

First off: `CarWheels` and `BicycleWheels` do not implement the `wheels` interface. This is because your `GetCount` methods use pointer receivers:

```golang
func (w *CarWheels) GetCount() int { return w.Count }
func (w *BicycleWheels) GetCount() int { return w.Count }
```

thus `*CarWheels` and `*BicycleWheels` (pointers to structs) implement the `wheels` interface, but the structs themselves do not. I'd simply remove the pointer receivers since these structs are very small (effectively just `int`s) and there's no need to "box" them using pointers (doing so would just incur overhead):

```golang
func (w CarWheels) GetCount() int { return w.Count }
func (w BicycleWheels) GetCount() int { return w.Count }
```

Alternatively, if your real structs are larger, you could of course also make your `GetWheels` methods return *pointers to the wheels* rather than the *wheels themselves*.

Second: Your function has a signature of `func Map2Vehicle[T vehicle[wheels]](v T) *Vehicle`. This means `v` must be a `vehicle` where the `GetWheels` method has return type `wheels`, not any return type implementing `wheels`. The solution to this issue is to make `GetWheels` functions return the abstract `wheels` type rather than the specific types:

```golang
func (c *Car) GetWheels() wheels { return c.Wheels }
func (b *Bicycle) GetWheels() wheels { return b.Wheels }
```

If you do this, your code will run as expected.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the specific types, you'll have to make the wheels a second generic parameter of the function:

```golang
func Map2Vehicle[W wheels, T vehicle[W]](v T) *Vehicle
```

Go will be unable to infer `W` (it seems generic type inference doesn't nest), so you have to make the type of wheels explicit at the call site now (it can still infer the type of the vehicle however):

```golang
v1 := Map2Vehicle[CarWheels](&c)
v2 := Map2Vehicle[BicycleWheels](&b)
```

---

If I were to refactor this, I would eliminate the generics entirely by having the `GetWheels` method return the `wheels` interface type; then `Map2Vehicle` can just operate on any `vehicle`, and `vehicle` doesn't need to be generic:

```golang
type vehicle interface {
    GetName() string
    GetWheels() wheels
}

func Map2Vehicle(v vehicle) *Vehicle {
    return &Vehicle{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s with %d wheels", v.GetName(), v.GetWheels().GetCount()),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create two values of different types, a Car and a Bicycle, then use the `Map2Vehicle` function to map each value to a Vehicle type?

Playground Link : https://play.golang.com/p/lPFoFEsjIeD

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := Car{Name: "MyCar", Wheels: CarWheels{Count: 4}}
    b := Bicycle{Name: "MyBicycle", Wheels: BicycleWheels{Count: 2}}
    v1 := Map2Car(c)
    v2 := Map2Bicycle(b)
    fmt.Println(v1, v2)
}

// ---------------- Car
type Car struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels CarWheels
}

type CarWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (c *Car) GetName() string      { return c.Name }
func (c *Car) GetWheels() CarWheels { return c.Wheels }
func (w *CarWheels) GetCount() int  { return w.Count }

// ---------------- Bicycle

type Bicycle struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels BicycleWheels
}

type BicycleWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (b *Bicycle) GetName() string          { return b.Name }
func (b *Bicycle) GetWheels() BicycleWheels { return b.Wheels }
func (w *BicycleWheels) GetCount() int      { return w.Count }

// ---------------- Vehicle
type Vehicle struct {
    Name string
}

func Map2Car(c Car) *Vehicle {
    return &Vehicle{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s with %d wheels", c.GetName(), c.GetWheels()),
    }
}

func Map2Bicycle(b Bicycle) *Vehicle {
    return &Vehicle{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s with %d wheels", b.GetName(), b.GetWheels()),
    }
}
```

**output**: [image]

Comment: The question is "[h]ow to map 2 different types (Car, Bicycle) with one generic mapping function (Map2Vehicle) to a Vehicle type"; this answer fails to answer that and instead just duplicates the code for the two different types.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to use generics in Go to map different types (`Car` and `Bicycle`) to a common `Vehicle` type. However, you're running into an error because the types `Car` and `Bicycle` have different implementations for the `GetWheels()` method.

To solve this problem, you can modify your code to use an interface instead of a concrete type for the `Wheels` field in both `Car` and `Bicycle` structs. By doing so, you can define a single implementation of `GetWheels()` that satisfies the `wheels` interface for both `CarWheels` and `BicycleWheels`. Here's an updated version of your code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// ------- Car
type Car struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels wheels // Use interface instead of concrete type
}

type CarWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (c *Car) GetName() string      { return c.Name }
func (c *Car) GetWheels() wheels    { return c.Wheels }
func (w *CarWheels) GetCount() int  { return w.Count }

// ------- Bicycle
type Bicycle struct {
    Name   string
    Wheels wheels // Use interface instead of concrete type
}

type BicycleWheels struct {
    Count int
}

func (b *Bicycle) GetName() string          { return b.Name }
func (b *Bicycle) GetWheels() wheels        { return b.Wheels }
func (w *BicycleWheels) GetCount() int      { return w.Count }

// ------- Common Interfaces -------
type wheels interface {
    GetCount() int
}

type vehicle interface {
    GetName() string
    GetWheels() wheels
}

// ------- Vehicle
type Vehicle struct {
    Name string
}

func Map2Vehicle(v vehicle) *Vehicle {
    return &Vehicle{
        Name: fmt.Sprintf("%s with %d wheels", v.GetName(), v.GetWheels().GetCount()),
    }
}

func main() {
    c := Car{Name: "MyCar", Wheels: &CarWheels{Count: 4}} // Pass a pointer to CarWheels
    b := Bicycle{Name: "MyBicycle", Wheels: &BicycleWheels{Count: 2}} // Pass a pointer to BicycleWheels
    
    v1 := Map2Vehicle(&c)
    v2 := Map2Vehicle(&b)
    fmt.Println(v1.Name, v2.Name)
}
```

Now, the code should compile and produce the output you expect:

```
MyCar with 4 wheels MyBicycle with 2 wheels
```